# Set Minutes Always 00

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to set minutes always `:00`.. What should I do to make it working.

Code

```
mytime:any;
var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(22);
  this.myTime = (new Date(d.setHours(22))).toISOString();
  console.log(this.myTime)
```

Comment: Is this Javascript or TypeScript?

Comment: Sorry.. this is TypeScript

Comment: You can use `d.setMinutes(0)`.

Comment: How to combine with `setHours`

Comment: Try with `d.setHours(22, 0, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to set the time to "on the hour", then you  need to set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to `0`, using `d.setHours(22, 0, 0, 0);`

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(22, 0, 0, 0);

var myTime = (new Date(d)).toISOString();
console.log(myTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.setMinutes(..)` to set the date's minutes value.
Also, you're calling `.setHours(..)` twice with the same value which is redundant.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(22);
d.setMinutes(22);
this.myTime = (new Date(d)).toISOString();
```